# Error al dividir en un function

Tags: sql

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS amountInP $$
CREATE FUNCTION amountInP (euros INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
SELECT amountInP.euros/166.386 AS 'Pessetes' ;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

SELECT amountInP(2000);
```

Estoy haciendo esta function y me esta devolviendo el siguiente error

```
  #1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a function
```

Mi idea era, pasarle un numero por pantalla y dividirlo por esa cantidad

Comment: Para obtener las pesetas deberías **multiplicar** la cantidad en euros, un € es 166'386 pesetas

Comment: Ya está solucionado

Comment: igual esta devolviendo un float no un integer cuando divides dos numeros asi sea entero te devolvera un float /double y no veo donde asignas el valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que guardar el resultado de la sentencia en una variable y luego retornarla. De la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT amountInP.euros/166.386 into {nombre_variable}
```

Declara la variable previamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, he hecho eso y ya funciona